# Not able to import sparkdl in jupyter notebook

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to use spark deep learning library(https://github.com/databricks/spark-deep-learning) in jupyter notebook.

When I try to "import sparkdl" in jupyter notebook I am getting error "no module found".

When I am running the below command in cli

```
pyspark --packages databricks:spark-deep-learning:1.5.0-spark2.4-s_2.11
```

I am able to import sparkdl in the spark shell and its working.

How can I use this library in jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the snippet that I use with PySpark 2.4. You will need a connection to the web to be able to install the package.

```
# Import libraries
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Creating SparkSession
spark = (SparkSession
            .builder
            .config('spark.jars.packages', 'databricks:spark-deep-learning:1.5.0-spark2.4-s_2.11')
            .getOrCreate()
)

# Import Spar-Deep-Learning-Pipelines
import sparkdl
```

Comment: This solution requires a web connection. I would be interested if anyone knows how to install `sparkdl` from a local .jar file.

Answer (score 0):

You can check several points:

1. use `%conda list|grep "sparkdl"` in jupyter notebook cell to check if **sparkdl** is installed as you wish.
2. virtual environment. Is **sparkdl** installed into another virtual environment?

hope this could help u.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to download sparkdl jar file using below command:

```
wget https://repos.spark-packages.org/databricks/spark-deep-learning/1.5.0-spark2.4-s_2.11/spark-deep-learning-1.5.0-spark2.4-s_2.11.jar
```

Second you have to install sparkdl pypi package using below command:

```
pip install sparkdl
```

Then you can use the below snippet in jupyter notebook:

```
    import findspark
    findspark.init()

    from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
    from pyspark import SparkContext
    conf = SparkConf().set("spark.jars", "./spark-deep-learning-1.5.0-spark2.4-s_2.11.jar")
    conf.setAppName("ML")
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    spark = SparkSession(sc)

    import sparkdl
```

This solution doesn't require a web connection once you download the jar file [Krystof](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10148673/krystof)